# JSON in Java Android

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am trying to send data to my php server using JSON but I get this error

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: unable to parse json
```

I am not experienced with JSON... Here is my java code

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
                json.addProperty("xxx4", "" + userid);
                json.addProperty("xxx3", "" + name);
                json.addProperty("xxx2", "" + aboutYourself.getText().toString());
                json.addProperty("xxx1", "Male");
                json.addProperty("xxx", "blabla" );





                Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load("xxx.com/json.php")
                        .setJsonObjectBody(json)
                        .asJsonObject()
                        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                                // do stuff with the result or error
                                Log.e("Error/Non-Error: ", "Error?: " + e + " Result?: " + result);
                            }
                        });
```

and my php code since I am trying to understand this

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

I used the example code form the website

Answer (score 2):

Try importing

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

and below would be the Code should look like :

```
try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("xxx4", "" + userid);
            json.put("xxx3", "" + name);
            json.put("xxx2", "" + aboutYourself.getText().toString());
            json.put("xxx1", "Male");
            json.put("xxx", "blabla");

            Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load("xxx.com/json.php")
                    .setJsonObjectBody(json)
                    .asJsonObject()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                            // do stuff with the result or error 
                            Log.e("Error/Non-Error: ", "Error?: " + e + " Result?: " + result);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Exceptionen is never thrown be cause it is already being handled here
`public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {`

Answer (score 0):

don't use print_r function, i would not create JSON notation, try code below

```
<?php json_encode($_POST); ?>
```